# can this code be rewritten more elegantly, in F#

Tags: f#

with an array like this:

```
let a = [| 1.; 2.; nan; 4.; 5. |]
```

I know that the last value is **not** a NaN (the list comes from an operation that generates leading NaNs) I want to scan the list from the end and if the value is a nan, replace it with the previous value.

In the case, the output would be:

```
[| 1.; 2.; 4.; 4.; 5. |]
```

first, I made this monstrocity:

```
Array.append a [|a.[^0]|] |> Array.pairwise |> Array.rev |> Array.map (fun (a, b) -> if Double.IsNaN(a) then b else a) |> Array.rev
```

then a cleaner loop:

```
seq {
    for i = a.Length - 1 downto 0 do
        yield if Double.IsNaN(a.[i]) then a.[i+1] else a.[i]
} |> Seq.rev |> Seq.toArray
```

I was thinking that maybe foldBack would work:

```
Array.foldBack (fun x acc -> Array.append acc (seq {yield if Double.IsNaN(x) then acc.[^0] else x} |> Seq.toArray)) a Array.empty
```

but this is ugly as well..

I can't help to think that there has to be a simple elegant way to do this... anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can make your `foldBack` solution a lot cleaner by realizing that `seq { yield foo } |> Seq.toArray` is the same as just `[|foo|]`:

```
Array.foldBack (fun x acc -> Array.append acc [|if Double.IsNaN(x) then acc.[^0] else x|]) a Array.empty
```

---

But a better approach is `scan`. It's a nice little function that's kind of like `map`, but each iteration also has access to the result of the previous one. Except, of course, since you're going back-to-front, you'll have to use `scanBack`:

```
Array.scanBack (fun x prev -> if Double.IsNaN x then prev else x) a nan
```

The only problem is that the "seed" of the scan (which is the last parameter - in my example `nan`) will remain in the resulting array, becoming its last element. So you'd have to filter it out afterwards, but I didn't think it would be a problem since you seemed to be ok reallocating multiple arrays in your `foldBack` approach:

```
Array.scanBack (fun x prev -> if Double.IsNaN x then prev else x) a nan
|> Array.takeWhile (not << Double.IsNaN)
```

---

Alternatively, you can remember that arrays are mutable, and simply mutate your original array:

```
for i in 0..(Array.length a - 1) do
    if Double.IsNaN a.[i] then a.[i] <- a.[i+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single `Array.mapi`. This is like `Array.map` but it provides the index of each item.

```ml
let fillNans xs =
    xs
    |> Array.mapi (fun i x -> if Double.IsNaN x then xs.[i+1] else x)
```

Comment: What about the last element of the array? Surely x.[i+1] will go beyond the array boundary?

Comment: An exception would be thrown. The question already states the last item is not NaN and there's no defined behaviour.